# MySQL query for Group wise Summary

Tags: mysql

My Table Like this

```
Attendance
----------

Studentid | Date       | Status
--------------------------------
1         | 2017-01-01 | Present
1         | 2017-01-02 | Present
1         | 2017-01-03 | Absent
1         | 2017-01-04 | Presnt
2         | 2017-01-01 | Absent
2         | 2017-01-02 | Present
2         | 2017-01-03 | Absent
2         | 2017-01-04 | Presnt
```

I want to write a Mysql Query to get the output like this.

```
StudentID | PresentCount  | AbsentCount
1         |       3       |     1
2         |       2       |     2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT StudentId, SUM(Status='Present') as PresentCount, SUM(Status='Absent') AS AbsentCount FROM Attendance GROUP BY StudentId;
```

Also there would be a problem if your field values have different spellings for 'Absent' and 'Present'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some spelling problems with the 'present' word.
This should work fine.

```
SELECT Studentid AS StudentID ,SUM(Status !='Absent') PresentCount  ,
    SUM(Status='Absent') AS AbsentCount FROM Attendance 
    GROUP BY Studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this query. This is what you want. Here is sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e3f40/31)

```
select id, max(PresentCount), max(AbsentCount) from (select id, sum(status='Present') as PresentCount, sum(status='absent') as AbsentCount from Student group by id, status) as table1 group by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT StudentID, Date,Status FROM Attendance WHERE StudentID=1

SELECT StudentID, Date,Status FROM Attendance WHERE StudentID=2

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT Studentid,
    SUM(Status='Present') PresentCount  ,
    SUM(Status='Absent') AS AbsentCount FROM Attendance 
    GROUP BY Studentid
```

Try above query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

```
SELECT 
    Studentid, 
    sum(case when Status = 'Present' then 1 else  0 end) AS PresentCount,  
    sum(case when Status = 'Absent' then 1 else  0 end ) AS AbsentCount
FROM 
    Attendance 
GROUP BY 
    Studentid
```